# how can i return multiple database record from a class in OOP programming

Tags: php, mysql, oop, class

Lets say i have a class like this

```
class book {
    public $title;
    public $author;
    public $page_num;
        .....
        ....

 public function show_book($limit=1){
         .... 
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT title,author,page_num  FROM book limit=$limit");

         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
         $this->title=$row['title'];
         $this->author=$row['author'];
         $this->page_num=$row['page_num'];
          }

        }
```

and then i can use it like :

```
 $book = new book();
 $book->show_book();
 echo $book->title." ".$book->author ...... ;
```

---

this works for one book 
what if i want to show 7 books ?
this is not working for `$book->show_book($limit=7);` 
i can make 7 objects but  i think there's a better way

Comment: You've got no WHERE clause, so I'd guess that you only have one record in the `BOOK` table...

Comment: Why, oh why, have you got public fields?! If you are going to use OOP, please don't break encapsulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rename the function `show_books` and have it return an array of `book` objects.  When you have no matches you return an empty array, otherwise you return all of the matching elements.  It probably makes the most sense as a static method rather than an instance method.

```
public static function show_books($limit=1){
     .... 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT title,author,page_num  FROM book limit=$limit");
    $books = array();

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
          $book = new book();
          $book->title=$row['title'];
          $book->author=$row['author'];
          $book->page_num=$row['page_num'];
          $books[] = $book;
     }
     return $books;
}

$books = Book::show_books(7);
```

Answer (score 1):

The class book represents one book (as the name suggests).

So it would be better if your move the `show_books()` method from this class to another place.

Now, you can modify it to return an array of the found books: In the while loop you need to create new book objects for each record you get from the query.